# Doxygen not documenting static classes?

Tags: c#, documentation, static, doxygen

I've been recently using Doxygen for a project of mine. I'm having a problem though that it won't generate the proper documentation for a C# static class. Is there some option I have to enable?

My complete source code for the relevant class is [here](http://codepad.org/2omMd8yM). And the doxygen file for the namespace is listed [here](http://lastyearswishes.com/static/EFramework/doxygen/html/namespace_earlz_1_1_e_framework.html). Also, my Doxyfile is [here](http://codepad.org/ZNAQLbEu). It was generated from doxywizard using almost default settings.

As you can see, the class's short description is generated, but the class does not have a page of it's own to see the (documented) static methods and members. Also, the class is not listed in the class index, or really anywhere else. What is the problem?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It's been a while since I've created a doxygen config, but try changing the value of EXTRACT_STATIC to YES, and you should get what you're looking for.

Comment: I wonder why they decided to do this. It seems to me if you set "all" to "yes", it should take everything with the exception of things that are later explicitly excluded. Not "yes except for these specific things, and you wont know until you look into the doxyfile or search on google".

Answer (score 27):

Just in case anyone is using the Doxywizard GUI rather than editing the Doxyfile by hand, the EXTRACT_STATIC flag is listed on the Expert tab under Build:

[image]

Comment: Heh, I actually was using the wizard when I asked this. I imagine it was just obvious to look for the setting in expert mode

Comment: @Earlz: I had the exact issue described in your question and this was one of the first links that a Google search brought me to. I find the GUI a bit easier to use and I figured the mentioned setting MUST be in there somewhere. The image is there so I can point people to it in future :-)

Comment: Much appreciated guys